# Incompatible operand types between K and int Java

Tags: java

I am making a hashtable with linear probing collision. I am trying to add the elements of the hashtable to a Set or to a Collection. The way I have set up my hashtable is that it is an array of Nodes that contain a "key" of generic type K and a "value" of generic type V. Indices in the table that do not have a node in the array are null, but indices that originally had a node but were deleted are marked with a Node that contains new Node(-1, -1). When I go to print the hashtable, I want to avoid printing the deleted spots (indices that contain the key -1). Here is the relevant code:

Methods to add to the set or collection (in hashtable class)

```
@Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        Set<K> s = new HashSet<K>();
        for(int i=0; i<this.hashtable.length; i++) {
            if(this.hashtable[i] != null && this.hashtable[i].key != -1)
                s.add(this.hashtable[i].key);
        }
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        LinkedList<V> l = new LinkedList<V>();
        for(int i=0; i<this.hashtable.length; i++) {
            if(this.hashtable[i] != null && this.hashtable[i].key != -1)
                l.add(this.hashtable[i].val);
        }
        return l;
    }
```

Node class (NOT hashtable class):

```
private final class Node<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>  {
        public K key;
        public V val;

        public Node() {
            this.key = null;
            this.val = null;
        }

        public Node(K theKey, V theValue) {
            this.key = theKey;
            this.val = theValue;
        }
    }
```

Main Method within the actual hashtable class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJHUHashMap<Integer, String> m = new MyJHUHashMap<>();
        m.put(1, "1!");
        m.put(2, "2!");
        m.put(3, "3!");
        m.put(4, "4!");
        m.put(5, "5!");
        m.put(6, "6!");
        m.put(7, "7!");
        m.put(8, "8!");
        m.put(9, "9!");
        m.put(10, "10!");
        m.put(11, "11!");
        m.put(12, "12!");
        m.put(13, "6!");
        m.put(14, "7!");
        m.put(15, "8!");
        m.put(16, "9!");
        m.put(17, "10!");
        m.put(18, "11!");
        m.put(19, "12!");
        m.put(20, "10!");
        m.put(21, "11!");
        m.put(22, "12!");
        m.put(23, "23!");
        System.out.println(m.get(4));
        System.out.println(m.get(12));
        System.out.println(m.get(25));
        System.out.println(m.containsKey(22));
        System.out.println(m.containsKey(35));
        m.remove(23);
        m.remove(18);
        //m.put(7, 7);
        System.out.println(m.hashtable.length);
        System.out.println(m.size());
        for(int i=0; i<m.hashtable.length; i++) {
            if(m.hashtable[i] != null && m.hashtable[i].key != -1)
                System.out.print(m.hashtable[i].key + " ");
        }
    }
```

The length seems correct, the size seems correct, and the keys do print out, however, -1 values are included. To overcome this, I wrote "this.hashtable[i].key != -1" in the methods. However, I get the error "Incompatible operand types K and int" in the keySet() and values() method, but not in the main method. Can anyone point out how to overcome this?

Comment: What if your `hashtable` contains `Node` objects with strings?

Comment: Good point, let me try making the deleted node values a new Node(null, null) instead of new Node(-1, -1).

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `Node` from the table when it's deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use -1 as a "special key value", since your key must be of type K (and K can be anything: a string, a date, etc).

Use null instead.